# How to search RealmList field of RealmObject in a single query

Tags: java, android, database, realm

Say I have a class:

```
public class Company extends RealmObject {

    private String companyId;
    private RealmList<CompanyMember> companyMembers;

}
```

Where the class CompanyMember looks like:

```
public class CompanyMember extends RealmObject {

    private String id;
    private String name;

}
```

Is it possible, using a single query in realm, to search a specific Company object's 'companyMembers' list based on a CompanyMember objects 'name' field?

For example, search Company 123's CompanyMember list for all CompanyMember's with a name containing 'abc', and return a list of these matching CompanyMembers.

Currently I am retrieving the entire company from Realm and iteratively searching the member list for a match, but this does not seem to be the best way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, like so:

```
Company company = realm.where(Company.class).equalTo("companyId", "123" ).findFirst();
RealmList<CompanyMember> companyMembers = company.getCompanyMembers();
RealmResults<CompanyMember> filteredMembers = companyMembers.where().contains("name", "abc").findAll();
```

Comment: Is it possible using findAll() where I need to add a condition on some property in 'CompanyMember'?