# Find all RealmObjects that have inside a list a given RealmObject

Tags: java, android, realm

Lets say I have this class (it already has an id property but it's already auto generated by realm):

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
   private String name;
   private String username;
}
```

And another one that has a list of Users inside:

```
public class Ride extends RealmObject {
    private String tripName;
    private String rideType;
    private RealmList<User> usersJoined;
}
```

I just want to do a query to realm to get a list of Rides where the user is inside. I found another [question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43584258/12261640) but in that case the asker already has the object that have the whole list and he just need to find the user inside that spefic object property list, but in my case I want to get the Rides where the user (that I already know) is inside. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of querying the Ride objects whose usersJoined list contains the user in question?

Comment: Yes thats maybe the only way as I can see. Just getting all the rides and querying them one by one.

Comment: That's not needed. It's a simple query that can be done in one line of code. I don't know android/java but in Swift it's `let rides = realm.objects(Ride.self).where { $0.usersJoined.contains(user)}`. I am pretty sure there is something equivalent for your coding platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed using `stream().filter` :

```
RealmResults<Ride> rides = realm.where(Ride.class).findAll();

List<Ride> = rides.stream().filter(ride -> ride.getUsersJoined().contains(givenUser)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```